# How can I split a "Lastname, Firstname" data into separate lastname and firstname columns?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, coldfusion

We have a table with a column called fullname with the format of "Lastname, Firstname"

I added new columns to the table so we can separate the lastname and the firstname, but I can't figure out how to go about it. The code below is what I used but "listFirst is not a recognized built-in function name."

```
<cfquery name="splitname" datasource="dsn">
UPDATE dbo.employees
SET
  lastname = listFirst(fullname, ","),
  firstname = listRest(fullname, ", ")
</cfquery>
```

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: You have no idea the can of worms this will open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way (this will not be the best way to do this. But it looks like an one time thing. So it should be fine.) is to select the rows as a separate query and update each row in a loop. Also you will need to evaluate the list functions before passing them to the query. Also use `<cfqueryparam>` to make the strings safe for query.

```
<cfquery name="splitname" datasource="dsn">
    SELECT empID, fullname 
    FROM dbo.employees
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="splitname">
    <cfquery datasource="dsn">
        UPDATE dbo.employees
        SET
            lastname = <cfqueryparam value="#trim(listFirst(splitname.fullname, ","))#" cfsqltype="varchar">,
            firstname = <cfqueryparam value="#trim(listlast(splitname.fullname, ","))#" cfsqltype="varchar">
        WHERE empID = <cfqueryparam value="#splitname.empID#" cfsqltype="varchar">
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: I will have to disagree. A `cfquery` should never be inside a `cfloop`. You will beat up your database. This is something that is _MUCH_ better suited to being done in SQL itself. It's not really a ColdFusion issue.

Comment: Granted, I should have included that this _will_ work, but it will be hard er on resources than it needs to be. CF shouldn't do this work.

Comment: Looping is also signifigantly slower. It's equivalent to using a cursor.. not something you'd want to do with a large number of records. Though I do understand this is probably a one-off, still..

Comment: _Almost_ like a cursor. A SQL cursor will at least stay within the same database connection. In a `cfloop`, it will reconnect to the database for every loop, then send the generated query, then disconnect, then repeat until the loop's done. For more than just a few rows, it can be pretty brutal to your system.

Comment: @Shawn - Very true

Comment: Well, guys this looked just like a one time thing. Did not want to go much into best practices. It might just confuse the post owner. Sometimes it's better to learn one thing at a time. I'll try to improve my answer FWIW.

Comment: On a second note, you guys have done a good job of doing that. I might just keep it like this.

Comment: @RRK - I hear what you're saying (and know you're aware of it already), but things like looping within a query can have a VERY negative effect on busy servers/applications when a lot of data is involved.  Since we don't always know an asker's experience level, how much data - or for that matter, who else will come across the answer in the future and copy and paste it wholesale - best not to assume. IMHO, better to go with "best practices" whenever possible. Plus, as it turns out, that happens to be the simplest approach in this case. So win-win all around :-)

Answer (score 3):

This shouldn't be done in ColdFusion. This is a problem with the data and any data transformations should be handled on the SQL Server itself. There's no need to pull data back to CF, have CF manipulate the data, then pass the manipulated data back to SQL.

And as was mentioned in other comments, you are opening up a huge can of unintended worms by making this change. Names can be incredibly difficult to work with.

This answer relies on the fact that your name data consists of a last name, followed by a comma, followed by the rest of the name. It will trim the first and last names and remove the first comma, but again be wary of `Garbage In, Garbage Out.`.

You can pass a query into the SQL like so:

```
<cfquery name="splitname" datasource="dsn">
    UPDATE dbo.employees
    SET lastname = ltrim(rtrim(left(fullname,charindex(',',fullname+',')-1)))
      , firstname = ltrim(rtrim(substring(fullname,charindex(',',fullname+',')+1,len(fullname))))
</cfquery>
```

You can see it in SQL at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=85fc8abfdbb02c469e28c2e4dd1df4f5.

Comment: And for some excellent reading about why parsing names can be oh so much fun: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you failed to put your CF functions in # signs and quotes.

```
<cfquery name="splitname" datasource="dsn">
UPDATE dbo.employees
SET
  lastname = '#listFirst(fullname, ",")#'
  , firstname = '#listRest(fullname, ", ")#'
</cfquery>
```

You really should use  though.

```
<cfquery name="splitname" datasource="dsn">
UPDATE dbo.employees
SET
  lastname = '<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" 
       value="#listFirst(fullname, ",")#">'
</cfquery>
```

As a best practice, I would sanitize variables BEFORE the SQL statement and use the trim function to get rid of spaces.

```
<cfscript>
    firstname = trim(listFirst(fullname, ","));
    lastname = trim(listLast(fullname, ","));
</cfscript>

<cfquery name="splitname" datasource="dsn">
UPDATE dbo.employees
SET
  firstname = '<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#firstname#">'
  , lastname = '<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#firstname#">'
</cfquery>
```

Also, we have been trying to use SQL's DECLARE statement to define the variables there. This makes it really easy to give complex queries to your DBA and have them be able to work with them quickly. Also, many queries use the same variables multiple times so it's much easier and cleaner to declare them at the top of the list.

```
<cfscript>
    firstname = listFirst(fullname, ",");
    lastname = listLast(fullname, ",");
</cfscript>

<cfquery name="splitname" datasource="dsn">

    DECLARE @FirstName varchar(50) = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#firstname#">
    DECLARE @LastName varchar(50) = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#lastname#">

    UPDATE dbo.employees
    SET
      firstname = @FirstName
      , lastname = @LastName

</cfquery>
```

Comment: I tried before your last edit but I was getting and error about "fullname" not a recognized variable. I was able to use RRK's code, but thank you!

Comment: @EvikJames - In this case, pound signs won't help because "fullname" is a database column, not a CF variable and obviously CF functions can't execute in the database. Plus even if it were a CF variable, adding pound signs [wouldn't have the desired effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53893569/8895292). Side note, looks like there are some stray quotes surrounding the cfqueryparam. (Would fix them myself, but my edit would probably get rejected).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Shawn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53892648/8895292), one important thing no one's mentioned is that you may be laboring under a misconception about queries in CF. One that could potentially have some very unpleasant consequences to the database, if not careful.

#### Being able to intermix CFML and SQL doesn't mean your database server executes CFML code

Databases servers don't know a thing about CFML. In fact, a database server never even *sees* any CFML code within a cfquery. All CFML (and/or cfcript) code is executed by the CF application server, before the database server even enters the picture.

So what actually happens when you intermix CFML and SQL? Conceptually, when the code executes:

1. The CF server attempts to evaluate any CF tags/functions and
   convert them into literal values. Those values are then concatenated
   with the rest of the plain text SQL, to form one big SQL string.
2. CF then hands that SQL string to the database for execution
3. The database server attempts to execute the SQL string and returns any
   results to the CF server
4. The CF server converts the database results into objects, like
   a "Query".

So as you can see, there's absolutely no mixing of the two. CF does it's job processing any CFML. The database handles any SQL. Never the twain shall meet.

### What's the potential problem?

Take a query like this. It won't crash, but it won't produce the expected result either.

```
<cfset FORM.newAccountNumber = "1234,ABC">

<cfquery datasource="dsn">
   UPDATE someTable
   SET    AccountNumber = '#listFirst(FORM.newValue, ",")#'
</cfquery>
```

What actually happen is this. First, CF executes the list function which returns the literal string "1234".

```
   #listFirst(variables.newValue, ",")#
```

CF then plugs that literal into the rest of the SQL statement, producing this:

```
    UPDATE someTable
    SET    AccountNumber = '1234'
```

When sent to the database, that statement sets *every* single account number in the entire table to the same value: "1234". Almost certainly, not the desired result.

Understanding how CFML code is interpreted within queries can help avoid some truly unpleasant consequences to your database. Especially if you don't have recent backups...

Answer (score 0):

`Listgetat` will do the trick, for example;

```
listgetat(fullname,1)  
listgetat(fullname,2)
```

Comment: Will the code you provided work with records that has two first names, like "Peggy Sue"?

Comment: I still got the error: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]'listgetat' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: sure will, it splits on a ,

Comment: what version of coldfusion are you running?

Comment: CF 2016. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Downvoted because this does not solve the basic problem of using ColdFusion functions in an SQL command.  All it does is use different functions.

Comment: @JxG - It doesn't work because "fullname" isn't a CF variable. It's a database column. CF functions can't operate on database objects.

Comment: *the basic problem of using ColdFusion functions in an SQL command* Strictly speaking, you can't use CF functions *in* a sql command.